# Static pages Home page Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('home'))

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

While reading through the Harlts tutorial in chapter 5, section 5.3.4(pretty spec).
even after following all the instructions i am getting this error.

```
    Static pages Contact page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.29544 seconds
11 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:25 # Static pages Help page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:32 # Static pages About page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:39 # Static pages Contact page
```

Here is the content of **spec/support/utilities.rb** file

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

and the content of **static_pages_spec.rb** file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_content('Sample App') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('home')) }
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    it { should have_content('Help') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    it { should have_content('About') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('About')) }
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    it { should have_content('Contact') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The home page title text is meant to display just `Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App` without the `| Home` part.

So change

```
describe "Home page" do
  before { visit root_path }

  it { should have_content('Sample App') }
  it { should have_title(full_title('home')) }
  it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
end
```

to

```
describe "Home page" do
  before { visit root_path }

  it { should have_content('Sample App') }
  it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
  it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
end
```

So removing the `home` on the 5th line there

Comment: "home" is not the only one causing problem its happening with about, contact,help section too..

Comment: and what about the other sections like about , contact same problem has occurred for those one also.